# Can I use if/then to enforce property constraints contradicting those previously given?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I'm working with [a multi-part JSON schema](https://github.com/CECSpecialistI/UWLibCatProfiles/tree/master/uwSchemas/v009base) (but am new to JSON schemas).
The schema places constraints on a profile, which contains resource templates, each of which contains property templates.
I'm attempting to change the way that constraints are enforced on the properties within any given property template.

In the [schema module for property templates](https://github.com/CECSpecialistI/UWLibCatProfiles/blob/master/uwSchemas/v009base/uw-property-template.json), constraints are placed on the properties `"mandatory"`, `"repeatable"`, and `"type"` as follows:

```
"mandatory": {
  "type": ["boolean", "string"],
  "enum": ["true", "false"],
  "title": "Mandatory",
  "description": "Indication that a value for the property is required. If unspecified, defaults to false.",
  "default": false
},
```

[...]

```
"repeatable": {
  "type": ["boolean","string"],
  "enum": ["true", "false"],
  "title": "Repeatable",
  "description": "Indication that the property is repeatable. If unspecified, defaults to true.",
  "default": true
},
```

[...]

```
"type": {
  "type": "string",
  "enum": ["literal", "lookup", "resource"],
  "title": "Type",
  "description": "Type of value (literal / resource / lookup) that is allowed by this property."
},
```

I'd like to use an if then statement to indicate that if the value of another property is `-1` (an indicator that the property template has been added to the profile but not yet filled in with values), it needn't conform to the rules above. In fact, I'd like to make sure that the values for the properties above are empty strings in this case.

I tried to do this in the following way:

```
"allOf": [
```

*(some other if-thens here)*

```
    {
        "if": {
            "properties": {
                "uwFormOrder": {
                    "const": -1
                }
            }
        },
        "then": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/empty-PTs"
        }
    }
 ],
 "definitions": {
```

*(some other definitions here)*

```
"empty-PTs": {
      "properties": {
        "mandatory": {
          "const": ""
        },
        "repeatable": {
          "const": ""
        },
        "type": {
          "const": ""
        }
      }
    }
```

Is this approach* fundamentally wrong?

*This approach = adding an additional if/then inside the existing `"allOf"`, adding an additional definition insde the existing `"definitions"`.

One final note: I'm modifying a schema published openly [here](https://github.com/LD4P/sinopia/tree/master/schemas)--the original work is *not my own*, I'm just attempting to build a bit on it.

Comment: I'm not totally clear what exactly you're asking, but I'm going to TRY and answer it anyway with some general considerations for what I believe you're trying to achive.

Answer (score 0):

In simplified terms, JSON Schema validation keywords add constraints to your validation checking. You cannot later remove them.

In stead, you must construct `if/then/else` blocks to form the result you want.

By the looks of the schemas you linked to, it seems you already understand how to use `if/then/else` correctly.

As a note, you can nest `if/then/else` blocks. The value of each of those keyword must be a JSON Schema, which itself may make use of those keywords. The resulting nested `then` or `else` schema will "bubble up" the applicability chain to be applied where it was intended.

In essense, there is no keyword to ignore other used keywords.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Relequestal!
Can I ask for clarification on the following:  

> As a note, you can next `if/then/else` blocks.

Comment: Welcome! Should you have further questions, please feel feee to join the slack via the discussion link on the JSON Schema website. Also you can easily test your schemas using https://jsonschema.dev

Comment: Thank you for the link! Hadn't seen that one. 
You may have missed it earlier (I edited my comment), but I was hoping for clarification on the following bit from your response --> "As a note, you can next `if/then/else` blocks."
Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry that should have said “nest” rather than “next”. I’ll amend.

Comment: Thanks again @Relequestal. I [attempted](https://github.com/briesenberg07/bmrStuff/blob/master/jsonSchemas/uw-property-template-test.json) to use an `if/then/else` to enforce one set of minimal constraints in the case of a specific value for the `uwFormOrder` property and a different set of constraints in all other cases.
(I also had to make quite a few [other changes](https://github.com/briesenberg07/bmrStuff/commit/1eb0ecd5ba659487db2181b0cff4a4eb704a23c6) where one module referred to another, etc.)
Unfortunately, it now appears that no constraints are enforced at all!

Comment: @Relequestal forgive this one last harrassment but maybe [my initial if condition](https://github.com/briesenberg07/bmrStuff/blob/1eb0ecd5ba659487db2181b0cff4a4eb704a23c6/jsonSchemas/uw-property-template-test.json#L7) is off?
In any case thanks again for taking a look and providing the schema-test link earlier.

Comment: For debugging the path of validation through your schema, change schemas you expect to execute to `false`, which will cause the validation to fail. Boolean values are valid schemas, which is super helpful for debugging. Sorry I don't feel I can be much more help with out a specific new problem statement (probably a new question or asking for help on the slack server).

Comment: You're welcome re the link. If you want to support it's further development, you know what to do ;)